# TinyMCE, Upload to MySQL DB, and Echo with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am currently using TinyMCE on a text area on my website in a form, and I upload it to my database, on submit.

I understand that the `<p>` needs to be there as a root block, for styling. However, I can not figure out how to echo that information from the database, with the `<p>` tags acting as actual html tags.

They only display as if they're a literal string.

E.g.

In database:

```
<p>User entered text from textarea</p>
```

How it displays on the page:

```
<p>User entered text from textarea</p>
```

How I would like it to be displayed:

```
User entered text from textarea
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have looked around at other various stackoverflow questions regarding TinyMCE, but couldn't find one that answered my question.

Comment: They are probably HTML entities. Have you tried PHP's [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)? Make sure you use the correct flags and encoding. Of course, storing HTML in a database is usually a bad coding practice.